# Single letter variables in cmd

Tags: variables, cmd

Apologies for a silly and newbie question, but I have no IT background whatsoever, and I don't seem to be able to find an answer in google for that.

I am currently trying to understand (very) simple batch script which happens to be:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%i in (users.csv) DO dsadd user "cn=%%j
%%i %%k,ou=2013,ou=students,dc=[domain],dc=org"
```

The bits that is unclear for me are %%i, %%j, %%k. I can see that they represent the columns from the csv file, respectively 1,2,3, and that the output is in the order 2,1,3.

Now, my question is - are letters i, j, k for variables fixed? I can see that this works when I replace them with a, b, c respectively, so I guess not. So is it an agreed convention?

I guess that %%i in this bit `delims=," %%i in (users.csv)` determines what letter should correspond to the first token, and then the following tokens are assigned alphabetically to j and k?

Comment: `i` is probably the most common variable name to hold the current loop's index. You could easily replace it with `TheNumber` or anything else for that matter.

Comment: Are you sure this is bash? It looks like windows shell.

Comment: this is not bash, this is windows/dos batch file

Answer (score 0):

The following attributes apply to the for command:

- The for command replaces %variable or %%variable with each text string in the specified set until the command processes all of the files.
- For variable names are case-sensitive, global, and no more than 52 total can be active at any one time.
- To avoid confusion with the batch parameters %0 through %9, you can use any character for variable except the numerals 0 through 9. For simple batch files, a single character such as %%f works.
- You can use multiple values for variable in complex batch files to distinguish different replaceable variables.

[For - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)

The first letter defined will be the first token with the remaining tokens being the next letters alphabetically.

Type the command `for /?` for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the info - so, I can actually use anything for as this variable, even a word? Why "i","j" and "k" seem to be used most often in the Internet?

Comment: @Bartias  Unfortunately, NO  only single letters can be used as `for` command variables in batch.   i, k, and j are popular because i = index and programmers for languages like C liked this type of notation.